# Scala functional algorithm performance

Tags: performance, scala, erlang, immutability

I've been solving this year Code Jam task with Dijkstra.
Long story short. You have to find right 3 subsets of set of chars out of X element set of chars.

I implemented my algorithm in Scala. But it didn't meet the requirements. It run for more than 10 minutes and therefore it made me lose the assignment.

```
class Dijkstra extends CodeJamProblem{    
  override def run(input: List[String]): String = {

    val params :: letters :: Nil = input
    val l :: x :: Nil = params.split(" ").toList.map{_.toInt}
    val inputString = (1 to x).map{_ => letters}.reduce(_ + _).toCharArray.toList

    val rests = for(
      iRests <- check(inputString, 'i);
      jRests <- check(iRests, 'j);
      kRests <- check(jRests, 'k)
      if kRests.length == 0)
      yield true

    if(rests.length > 0) "YES" else "NO"
    "NO"
  }
  @tailrec
  final def check(input: List[Char], equalTo: Symbol, lq: Quaternion = ('l, false), r: List[List[Char]] = List()) : List[List[Char]] = {
    if(input.isEmpty) r
    else {
      val rest = input.tail
      val newq = lq * Quaternion(Symbol(input.head.toString), false)
      if (newq.symbol == equalTo && !newq.negative){
        check(rest, equalTo, newq, rest :: r)
      } else {
        check(rest, equalTo, newq, r)
      }
    }
  }
  override val linesPerInput: Int = 2
}

case class Quaternion(symbol: Symbol, negative: Boolean){
  def *(that: Quaternion) = {
    val negative = this.negative ^ that.negative
    val (symbol, negate) = (this.symbol, that.symbol) match {
      case ('l, a) => (a, false)
      case (a, 'l) => (a, false)
      case (a, b) if a == b => ('l, true)

      case ('i,'j) => ('k, false)
      case ('j,'k) => ('i, false)
      case ('k,'i) => ('j, false)

      case ('j,'i) => ('k, true)
      case ('k,'j) => ('i, true)
      case ('i,'k) => ('j, true)

    }
    Quaternion(symbol, negate ^ negative)
  }
}
```

I thought it's just about the algorithm itself. However then I implemented the same algorithm in Erlang and it ran in less than a second.

```
main(String) ->
  AtomList = [{list_to_atom([X]), false} || X <- String],
  Result = [ true ||    RestI <- find_rests(AtomList, {i, false}),
                        RestJ <- find_rests(RestI, {j, false}),
                        RestK <- find_rests(RestJ, {k, false}),
                        RestK == []
              ],
  case Result of
    [true | _] -> "YES";
    _ -> "NO"
  end.

find_rests(I, S) -> find_rests(I, S, {1, false}, []).
find_rests([], _, _, Rests) -> Rests;
find_rests(Input, Symbol, LastQ, Rests) ->
  [H | Rest] = Input,
  case mulpily(LastQ, H) of
    Symbol   -> find_rests(Rest, Symbol, Symbol, [Rest | Rests]);
    Q        -> find_rests(Rest, Symbol, Q, Rests)
  end.



multiply({Sym,Sign}, {Sym2, Sign2}) ->
  {S, N} = mul(Sym, Sym2),
  {S, Sign xor Sign2 xor N}.

mul(S, 1) ->
  {S, false};
mul(1, S) ->
  {S, false};
mul(S, S) ->
  {1, true};
mul(i,j) ->
  {k, false};
mul(j,k) ->
  {i, false};
mul(k,i) ->
  {j, false};
mul(j,i) ->
  {k, true};
mul(k,j) ->
  {i, true};
mul(i,k) ->
  {j, true}.
```

So there is my question. What makes Scala run so much slower. My guess is it's some object copying that I can't see. But if that's the case why does scala copy immutable structures?

For people trying to  understand the problem better here's the assignment
https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6224486/dashboard#s=p2

Comment: Are you sure the two implementations perform the same computation? (It would be a lot easier to compare the two if you'd chosen more similar identifiers!)

Comment: In the recursive call in `check`, you pass `rest` as the first argument, which is `input.tail` where input is the first parameter to this call of `check`.  In the Erlang version you pass `Rests`, which is the last parameter (which would  be `r`, in the Scala version). If the Erlang was to do the same as the scala, it would pass `Rest` not `Rests`

Comment: @Paul it's based on the exact same idea  
1. Converting to string to list. 2. Getting all rests of lists that reduce to "i" 3. Getting all rests of lists for each rest of list that reduce to "j". 4. Getting lists reducing to "k" for each rest of each rest of list.
5. Displaying these results of 4 that don't have any rest (use full string for algorithm)

Comment: Yes, I know it's the same idea. My supposition is that in fact it isn't implementing the same algorithm, but determining that is made unnecessarily more difficult because the identifiers are different so you need to keep a mental map of what one identifier means in the other implementation

Comment: And as you can see from my earlier comment above, I think the two do implement something different. And (to bang on about it) it would have been obvious had you used the same identifier names

Comment: @Paul
Yes. That one with Rests/Rest was a typo.
Just corrected it. 
Nevertheless both programs work for the same input (after correction) and Erlang is still much much faster.

Comment: I'm not really understanding the algorithm yet (and I don't know much Erlang), but there's  a test of `!newq.negative` in the Scala one which I don't see in the Erlang version. Have I missed something?

Comment: @Paul That's because in Erlang it's handled by pattern matching on tuple.
`{i, false}` in Erlang. And in scala `(newq.symbol == equalTo && !newq.negative)`

I can assure You that it's not about what the algorithm does. Because the results are the same for both programs. It's something about performance in Scala. Performance regarding copying of lists IMO.

Comment: OK, help me out. I don't see any pattern match of {i, false} in the Erlang version? And just because it's the same result doesn't mean it takes the same route to get there - I don't see anything in the Scala version that would suggest a lot of list copying. Do you have a profiler to get an idea of where the time goes? Or some idea of the memory consumption of both versions? And couuld you paste the actual Erlang code (there's a misspelling - "mulpily" - which means it can't be the actual code at the moment).

Comment: And you can patttern-match case classes in Scala too :)

Comment: Not that I think it will make much difference, but how about making inputString (etc) a List[Symbol] which avoids a lot of converting strings to Symbols?

Comment: OK, got the pattern matching bit, I'd missed that Symbol is constant for any one call to the toplevel find_rests

Comment: @Paul. True. That should help

Comment: I am new to scala. But will `Quaternion(symbol, negate ^ negative)` call inside the `def *(that: Quaternion)` try to call the contructor again creating infinte loop?

Comment: If that was a constructor yes. But that's just .*()  method.

Answer (score 1):

In actual fact, I doubt timing is your issue here. There are multiple issues I ran into while investigating your code.

1) If you look at your main method:

```
override def run(input: List[String]): String = {
    val params :: letters :: Nil = input
    val l :: x :: Nil = params.split(" ").toList.map{_.toInt}
    val inputString = (1 to x).map{_ => letters}.reduce(_ + _).toCharArray.toList

    val rests = for(
      iRests <- check(inputString, 'i);
      jRests <- check(iRests, 'j);
      kRests <- check(jRests, 'k)
      if kRests.length == 0)
      yield true

    if(rests.length > 0) "YES" else "NO"
    "NO"
  }
```

Your last line is `"NO"`. This means instead of returning `"No"` unless `rests.length > 0`, you are always returning `"No"`. (You can fix this by simply deleting the last `"NO"`)

2) I ran some test data found on the [page you linked](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6224486/dashboard#s=p2), namely "C-large-practice". It fails on the very first input with a number format exception. This is because one of the parameter numbers is `"209152663278"`, which is larger than `Int.MaxValue`. To fix this is a more complicated endeavor.

2a) 
Firstly, I changed this line:

```
val l :: x :: Nil = params.split(" ").toList.map{_.toInt}
```

By changing the toInt to toLong.

```
val l :: x :: Nil = params.split(" ").toList.map{_.toLong}
```

2b)
Also, we have to change part of the next line to handle long ranges, by changing this:

```
val inputString = (1 to x).map{_ => letters}.reduce(_ + _).toCharArray.toList
```

By adding an L after 1 to make it a long literal.

```
val inputString = (1L to x).map{_ => letters}.reduce(_ + _).toCharArray.toList
```

3) Even after these two changes, there is a slight issue. Still on our first test case, we have an error on this line:

```
val inputString = (1L to x).map{_ => letters}.reduce(_ + _).toCharArray.toList
```

Saying that it cannot map because there are `More than Int.MaxValue elements.` The way I whipped up to fix this was:

```
val inputLetters:mutable.ListBuffer[Char]=mutable.ListBuffer()
var count=0L
while(count < x){
    inputLetters++=letters.toCharArray()
    count+=1
    println("X is" + x + "count is" + count)
}
val inputString=inputLetters.toList
inputLetters.clear()
```

But this becomes a performance bottleneck, since it has to allocate a massive amount of memory. This might indicate where the slowdown in your program is. I'd recommend doing more testing and optimization with the datasets provided on the site you linked, if you want to improve the speed of your Scala version.

I don't have quite enough Erlang experience to debug your Erlang work, but I'd recommend testing the entire dataset provided before assuming it gives correct results at such a speed.